# starting gvim from the working directory

Tags: vim, ctags

Trying to run gvim 7.3 from the working directory (project location) seems impossible-- it defaults to the home directory which breaks my code browsing and pythoncomplete setup.

I've tried three approaches. First, calling gvim from the working directory:

```
cd /some/dir && gvim
```

Second, specifying a 'cd' command for gvim to execute

```
gvim -c 'cd /some/dir'
```

Third, telling it to open a particular file in that directory

```
gvim /some/dir/file.txt
```

In all cases, when i'm in gvim and type ':cd' to see the current directory what I get is my $HOME directory. Vim, on the ether hand, starts up at the working directory.

Does anyone know if there's a way around the problem or the reasoning behind this?

Comment: `:cd` without any argument will change the working directory to your home directory. You want to `:pwd` or print working directory. Could that be part of your problem?

Comment: aha, there were a few things going on... I was typing cd which would chdir me to $HOME as you explain. Once I figured that out code browsing worked but pythoncomplete didn't. It seems pythoncomplete does not solely rely on the tags files since adding a missing import fixed code completion. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cd` behaves differently in `Windows` and `Unix` system

- On `non-Unix` systems: Print the current directory name.
- On `Unix` systems: Change the current directory to the home directory.
- Use `:pwd` to print the current directory on all systems.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Set working directory to the current file](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Set_working_directory_to_the_current_file) solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

`$ cd /path/to/working/directory; gvim` works for me.